# Handling exceptions to avoid breaking of code

Tags: java, exception

I am writing code to make get request to around 10000 URLs and save the result in an excel. Now some URL are returning exception on sending a get request to them and my code breaks at that point. I want my code to run to make get requests for all the 10000 URLs even if some URL get request fails in between. Can someone give me some hint so that I can use it to avoid breaking of my code when a URL get request fails.

Comment: can we get relevant parts of the code ?

Comment: try-catch blocks for critical sections

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/: first link when googling for "exception tutorial".

Comment: Is there anything in the exceptions after a HTTP request that requires special attention beyond the usual try-catch-finally paradigm? Or is this Q just fishing for a design pattern for a menial task?

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch appropriate exceptions, and process them as needed, like this:

```
for(String someURL : myListOfURLS) { 
   try { 
       ResultThingy r = getURL(someURL);
   } catch(PossibleThingThatCouldGoWrong exc) { 
       System.err.println("Well, that didn't work, but onward!");
   } 
}
```